# Formula to remove entire words that start with certain characters

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I want a formula that searches a string for all occurrences of `http` and removes that entire link. For instance:

```
This is the best story ever http://www.usatoday.com make sure to read it twice. http://www.usatoday.com/image.jpg
```

would become:

```
This is the best story ever make sure to read it twice.
```

From what I've read, this should do it:

```
 =TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("http",A1)-1))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http",A1))+1)
```

but I'm still getting `#VALUE!`.

I'd like to be able to have the code find the URL at any point in the string. Also, if no URL is found, I'd just like the original string reprinted.

Any ideas?

Comment: + 1 Good question. Almost had me baffled :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(A1,FIND("http://",A1),IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http://",A1)),LEN(A1)+9)-FIND("http://",A1)+1,""))
```

if you're looking to remove URLS not just at end of sentence.

**IMO the following edit from @Siddharth Rout provides a better solution than the above.**

---

**Non VBA / Non Formula Method**

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring the `Find And Replace` Dialog Box.
2. In `Find What`, type "http://* " without the quotes. Notice there is a space after `*`
3. Keep the `Replace With` empty.
4. Click `Replace All`
5. Now in `Find What`, type "http://*" without the quotes. Notice there no space after `*`
6. Keep the `Replace With` empty
7. Click `Replace All`

And you are done.

Comment: Only removes the first occurrence of a link. I'm looking to remove all links.

Comment: Yea, it'd be 2, 3 max. What do you mean? Just doing a couple iterations of the same formula over different columns?

Comment: Okay: 

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("http",A1)),TRIM(REPLACE(A1,FIND("http",A1),IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND("http",A1)),LEN(A1)+9)-FIND("http",A1)+1,"")),A1)

Works if you iterate it over two or three columns. As of now, this is the best solution of all suggested.

Comment: + 1 Another good one. Just thinking aloud.. How about text to columns with space as delimiter and then deleting the cells which have http in them?

Comment: True, Like I said, just thinking aloud... :)

Comment: Ok try this for me `1` Press CTRL + H and type "http://* " without the quotes in the Find and in the Replace, keep it blank and do a replace all. Next `2` type "http://*" without the quotes and in the Replace, keep it blank and do a replace all. In the first one there is a space after "*"

Comment: No I won't post an answer. Too Lazy. If it works, amend your answer ;)

Comment: Updated your answer :)

Comment: It's 1:14 am. Time for bed now... Gnite :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own formula to use regexp expressions in Excel.

1. in Excel open Visual Basic Editor
2. Go to `Tools > References...`
   [image]
3. Check `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0`
   [image]
4. and `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`
   [image]
5. Then right-click your `VBAProject (Book1.xlsx)` on the left pane
   [image]
6. `Insert > Module`
7. Paste this code

   ```
   Public Function RgxReplace(aregexp As String, _
   astring As Range, _
   areplace As String) As String
   Dim re As RegExp
   Set re = New RegExp
   re.Pattern = aregexp
   RgxReplace = re.Replace(astring, areplace)
   End Function
   ```
8. And save

Now yoг have a new formula in your list

[image]
which you can use to regexp replace the string using patterns. In your case it will be
[image]

(special thanks to [vdasus](http://vdasus.com/author/vdasus/))

Comment: plus one for the details. :)

Comment: PC Only. It's case sensitive, so it needs to be \S+\S This only replaces the first occurrence of a link. Anyway to modify the expression to get all occurrences in a string? i.e. a string with two hyperlinks

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo, 1. "PC Only"?! - Excel only. 2. "It's case sensitive, so it needs to be \S+\S"?! - `\s` stands for last space and `\S+` for previous non-space chars after `http://` (please, read the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) first) 3. "This only replaces the first occurrence of a link"? - VBScript's `Replace()` must replace all occurrences

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,1,SEARCH("http",A1)-1))
```

No way to test it so i leave it to you.

Comment: Perfect. What is the MID/-1 doing here?

Comment: `Search` returns the position of `http`. subtracting 1 points the lenght of word the `Mid` function is to return. It will include the space but `Trim` will take care of it.

Comment: it doesn't work when url is in the middle of the string or in the beginning: `I visit http://stackoverflow.com every day`, so I think it's too fast to accept this answer, because it satisfies only one condition

Comment: @vladkras the OP is asking a simple question. So i presented a simple solution to his formula. :) If he however presented the same issue you've discussed then my answer would have been different as well.